# Java : Insert query-Exception

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a doubt regarding database operation.I have one insert query that should run for 10 times. the loop starts and inserted 4 or 5 val while inserting 6th, the  db connection got failed for a while and again connected. then what will happen,
whether it skips that particular val or throws exception or roll back th entire operation?

**EDIT  :  Sample Code**

```
try
{
    String sql_ji_inser="insert into job_input values (?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst_ji_inser=OPConnect.prepareStatement(sql_ji_inser);

    for(int i=0;i<v_new_data.size();i++)
            {
      Vector row=new Vector();
              row=(Vector)v_new_data.get(i);

              job_id=Integer.parseInt(row.get(0).toString());
              item_no=Integer.parseInt(row.get(1).toString());
              pst_ji_inser.setInt(1,job_id);
              pst_ji_inser.setInt(2,item_no);
              pst_ji_inser.addBatch();
            }
            System.out.println("No of rows inserted"+pst_ji_inser.executeBatch().length);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
           System.out.println("********Insert Exception*********************");
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return false;
    }
```

**Is this the right way**

```
try 
{
int count=0;// for checking no of inserting values
OPConnect.setAutoCommit(false);
String sql_ji_inser="insert into job_input values (?,?)";
PreparedStatement pst_ji_inser=OPConnect.prepareStatement(sql_ji_inser);
for(int i=0;i<v_new_data.size();i++)
    {
    job_id=Integer.parseInt(row.get(0).toString());
    item_no=Integer.parseInt(row.get(1).toString());
    pst_ji_inser.setInt(1,job_id);
    pst_ji_inser.setInt(2,item_no);
    pst_ji_inser.addBatch();
    count++;
    }
int norowinserted=pst_ji_inser.executeBatch().length;
if(count==norowinserted)
    {   
    OPConnect.commit();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
System.out.println("********Insert Exception*********************");
OPConnect.rollback();
ex.printStackTrace();
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how you're inserting the rows. If you're inserting them in a single transaction on a connection which has auto-commit turned off by `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` and you're commiting the connection after completing the insert queries using `connection.commit()` and you're explicitly calling `connection.rollback()` inside the catch block, then the entire transaction will be rolled back. Otherwise, you're dependent on environmental factors you have no control over.

#### See also:

- [When to call rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160756/in-jdbc-when-autocommit-is-false-and-no-explicit-savepoints-have-been-set-is-it/3161654#3161654)

---

**Update:** here's a rewrite of your code. Note that the connection and statement should be declared before the `try`, acquired in the `try` and closed in the `finally`. This is to prevent resource leaking in case of exceptions.

```
String sql = "insert into job_input values (?, ?)";
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;

try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

    for (List row : data) {
        statement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(row.get(0).toString()));
        statement.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(row.get(1).toString()));
        statement.addBatch();
    }

    statement.executeBatch();
    connection.commit();
    return true;
} catch (SQLException e) {
    if (connection != null) try { connection.rollback(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
} finally {
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

I am by the way not a fan of returning a `boolean` here. I'd just make the method `void`, let the `catch` `throw e` and put the calling code in a `try-catch`.

Comment: @ BalusC : Thank you ,I didnt use any autocommit() and rollback().in try block i used the insert query and using addbatch() for all values and finally executed using executeBatch()

Comment: Then fix it accordingly. By the way, `Vector` is really a legacy class. Is this a 15 year old codebase which you have to maintain? Since Java 1.2 the `ArrayList` was introduced as superior replacement to `Vector`.

Comment: @ BalusC : Kindly note the Edited post