# Which is the better approach nested try finally or one try with if condition

Tags: java, jdbc

For insert record in database with JDBC, there are two approaches :

1. Nested try.. finally : In this approach, nested try with finally use for close prepare statement and connection

   ```
   public void performInsert(String insertSQL) {
       try {
           Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
           try {
               PreparedStatement insertStmt = connection
                       .prepareStatement(insertSQL);
               try {
                   // bind value to prepare statements
                   insertStmt.executeUpdate();
               } finally {
                   insertStmt.close();
               }
           } finally {
               connection.close();
           }
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           // TODO: handle exception
       }
   }
   ```
2. single try with if condition in finally block : In this approach single try use and in finally block use if condition for close statement and connection:

   ```
   public void performInsertIF(String insertSQL) {
       Connection connection = null;
       PreparedStatement insertStmt = null;
       try {
           connection = dataSource.getConnection();
           insertStmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
           // bind value to prepare statements
           insertStmt.executeUpdate();
       }catch (SQLException e) {
           // TODO: handle exception
       } finally {
           if( insertStmt != null) {
               try {
                   insertStmt.close();
               } catch (SQLException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }

           if( connection != null) {
               try {
                   connection.close();
               } catch (SQLException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Both above approach is working fine, but which approach is better to use and why ?

Comment: If you have Java 7+, you can use try-with-resources as a superior third alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066501/how-should-i-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc

Answer (score 2):

In the above code both approaches work fine but second is better in a way because you check for a `null` object before calling `close()` on it. Calling `close()` on a null object will throw a `NullPointerException`.

In Java 7+ now, however, you can use a better alternative called [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: In the first approach both `connection` and `insertStmt` will not be null when `close()` is called.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel **In the above code both approaches work fine**

Comment: That is not my concern, you say _"but second is better ... because you check for a null object ... Calling close() on a null object will throw a NullPointerException"_. That doesn't apply to the first approach as neither `connection` or `insertStmt` can be `null` when `close()` is called in the code shown, invalidating your argument that the second approach is better because of that check

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You've failed to understand my argument. I meant that the second approach is better **in general**. I was not being specific to this example when I said __but second is better__.

Comment: I disagree - but that is mostly a matter of taste - the first approach is IMHO better (if you are unable to use try-with-resources that is). It requires less checks (like the null checks) at the cost of additional nested try-finally blocks.

Comment: I agree with you as you said, "but that is mostly a matter of taste."

Answer (score 1):

The best option (assuming Java 7 or higher) is to use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
public void performInsert(String insertSQL) {
    try (
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement insertStmt = connection
                    .prepareStatement(insertSQL);
    ) {
        // bind value to prepare statements
        insertStmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

After the try block ends, both `connection` and `insertStmt` will be closed automatically (in the reverse order of creation). The `connection` will even be closed if the statement prepare fails, or close of `insertStmt` fails.

Answer (score -1):

You should got with second approach.
Make a Utility with static methods, which close the resources with NULL checks.

```
public class DBUtils{
public static void closeConnection(Connection  con){
    if(con != null){
           // close the connection
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if con.close() throws an exception?

Comment: If you want to catch the Exception then, you should do what Punit mentioned in Second way. While using this utility ideally you should not throw the exception.

Answer (score -2):

I generally use a structure that is quite similar to your second example...

```
public void performInsertIF(String insertSQL) {
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement insertStmt = null;
try {
    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    insertStmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
    // bind value to prepare statements
    insertStmt.executeUpdate();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
finally {

    try {
        insertStmt.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ignore) {
    }

    try {
        connection.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ignore) {
    }
}
```

}

However, if you are really wanting to print the stacktrace for SQLExceptions in the finally block, I would personally go with this variation as I think it looks a bit tidier/cleaner...

```
public void performInsertIF(String insertSQL) {
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement insertStmt = null;
try {
    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    insertStmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
    // bind value to prepare statements
    insertStmt.executeUpdate();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
finally {

    try {
        insertStmt.close();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException ignore) {
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        connection.close();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException ignore) {
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You simply don't catch a `NullPointerException`. A `NullPointerException` simply proves that the code is buggy.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't catch the NPE as I would use the first example. I disagree, though, that the code is buggy as the two objects in the finally block may be null through no fault of the preceding code.

Comment: You've misunderstood me brother. I didn't say your code is buggy. I said if a program throws a NPE it is in most cases buggy and has no proper checks. Hence, catching a NPE is a bad practice.

Comment: But, surely, it depends on the context. Sure, catching/absorbing an NPE in the main flow is bad practice, but I personally don't believe that rule should apply in a finally block that is being used only to clean up.

Comment: ...especially as we know the objects may be null and we're not interested if they are.

Comment: But as you can see a simple null check is better and cleaner than a try-catch.

Comment: Not in this case, as we already have a catch block for the SQLException anyway - so in my example we have less code indentation. I think my code looks cleaner, but maybe it's just personal choice.