# Counting rows sql table with jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have trouble counting the rows of my sqltable. Using just the query in MS Studio works fine but when I try in Java I get an sql exception:

```
Connection con = null;
    Statement stat = null;
    int result = 0;
    int i;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=sa;password=123456; databaseName=RPA;");
        stat = con.createStatement();
        result = stat.executeUpdate("select count(*) FROM RPA_Users");

    }catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("cannot connect!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
```

Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: Nevermind I already found it guys, thanks as usual for the help!
My solution if someone is interested:

```
result = stat.executeQuery("select count(*) FROM /tablename/"); 
        result.next();
        rowCount = result.getInt(1);
```

Comment: can you show the entire exception message?

Comment: If you are using Java 7 and above, you can use try-with-resources to make the code more readable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8066594/812272

Comment: You should post your findings as your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `executeQuery` instead of `executeUpdate` for issuing database read queries

```
result = stat.executeQuery("select count(*) FROM RPA_Users");
```

Aside: Consider [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `executeUpdate()` for a query. This won't work.

You should switch to [`executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) This method returns a `ResultSet` that you will have to evaluate.

Comment: How do I evaluate/convert the ResultSet so that I can return an integer?
EDIT: no problem, I already found it!

Answer (score 0):

This is the full code:

```
{
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stat = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    int rowCount = -1;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=sa;password=123456; databaseName=RPA;");
        stat = con.createStatement();
        result = stat.executeQuery("select count(*) FROM RPA_Users");   
        result.next();
        rowCount = result.getInt(1);        
        }catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("cannot connect!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
    return rowCount;

}
```