# Java prepared statement in try-with-resources not working

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

Yesterday multiple people on Stack recommended using try-with-resources. I am doing this for all my database operations now. Today I wanted to change Statement to PreparedStatement to make the queries more secure. But when I try to use a prepared statement in try-with-resources I keep getting errors like 'identifier expected' or ';' or ')'.

What am I doing wrong? Or isnt this possible? This is my code:

```
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
        stmt.setInt(1, user);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {

        // if no record found
        if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
           return false;
        }
        // if record found
        else {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // log error but dont do anything, maybe later
        String error = "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "\nSQLState: " + e.getSQLState() + "\nVendorError: " + e.getErrorCode();
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: On the first line, change `;` to `) {`. (Silly typo?)

Answer (score 10):

A try-with-resource statement is used to declare (`Autoclosable`) resources. `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` are `Autoclosable`, so that's fine.

But `stmt.setInt(1, user)` is NOT a resource, but a simple statement. You cannot have simple statements (that are no resource declarations) within a try-with-resource statement!

Solution: Create multiple try-with-resource statements!

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS)) {
    executeStatement(conn);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // log error but dont do anything, maybe later
    String error = "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "\nSQLState: " + e.getSQLState() + "\nVendorError: " + e.getErrorCode();
    return false;
}

private void executeStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=? LIMIT 1")) {
        stmt.setInt(1, user);
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            // process result
        }
    }
}
```

(Please note that technically it is not required to put the execution of the SQL statement into a separate method as I did. It also works if both, opening the connection and creating the `PreparedStatement` are within the same try-with-resource statement. I just consider it good practice to separate connection management stuff from the rest of the code).

Comment: why? you can place the `Connection` and `PreparedStatement` inside the same resource creation block then uses `stmt`

Comment: That's right, but usually in real world applications opening the JDBC connection and doing SQL work is/should be separated. Of course you could also have everything in one single method.

Comment: But thanks for your remark. Added it to my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASS)) {
     PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");

        stmt.setInt(1, user);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery())

        // if no record found
        if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
           return false;
        }
        // if record found
        else {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // log error but dont do anything, maybe later
        String error = "SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "\nSQLState: " + e.getSQLState() + "\nVendorError: " + e.getErrorCode();
        return false;

    }
```

note that here, resource is your Connection and you have to use it in the try block `()`

Comment: really you should have the `PreparedStatement` inside the resource creation block as well so that it is closed properly.

Comment: ok agreed. Also, found a post on the same topic at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066501/how-should-i-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc  May be someone can mark this one as duplicate. I don't have that privilege yet.

Comment: That post doesn't cover this specific problem however.

Comment: @Ross I meant marking the question as duplicate. This question is asking about proper use of try-with-resources for JDBC, so as the one that I posted link to.

Comment: Also, the ResultSet is not closed when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
stmt.setInt(1, user);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()
```

...within the `try{ /*HERE*/ }`

This is because `stmt` is the resource being created `try (/*HERE*/) {}` to be used `try{ /*HERE*/ }`

**Try-with-resources**

```
try (/*Create resources in here such as conn and stmt*/)
{
  //Use the resources created above such as stmt
}
```

The point being that everything created in the resource creation block `implements AutoClosable` and when the `try` block is exited, `close()` is called on them all.
In your code `stmt.setInt(1, user);` is not an `AutoCloseable` resource, hence the problem.