# HikariCP not closing connections on close() (Connection Leak)

Tags: java, postgresql, database-connection, datasource, hikaricp

I'm using HikariCP 3.3.1 and PostgreSQL. But I've a problem with closing my connections, in Hikari config I set maximum pool size to 15 and minimum idle connection to 5, but after a few minutes of work with database I've found out connections don't closes, they stack more and more (almost 100 Idle connections right now). 
[image]

My Connector class:

***Connector.java***

```
public class Connector implements IConnector {
private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
private static HikariDataSource ds;

static {
    config.setDriverClassName(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getName());
    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/vskDB");
    config.setUsername("postgres");
    config.setPassword("root");
    config.setMinimumIdle(5);
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(15);
    config.setConnectionTimeout(20000);
    config.setIdleTimeout(300000);
    ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
}

public Connection getConnection() {
    log.info("getConnection() invoked");
    try {
        return ds.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Can't get connection from DataSource.");
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

Connector() {
}
}
```

And here's my DAO class (simplified):
***UserDAO.java***

```
public class UserDatabaseDAO implements UserDAO {
    private Connector connector = new Connector();
    private Connection dbConnection;

    @Override
    public void removeUser(Long id) {
        try {
            dbConnection = connector.getConnection();
            if (dbConnection == null)
                throw new ConnectException();

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ?");
            preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
            preparedStatement.execute();

        } catch (SQLException | ConnectException e) {
            log.error("Can't remove user from database");
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                dbConnection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error("Can't close connection");
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/870) I've found an issue with some facts about Hikari:
*You must call close() on the connection instance that HikariCP gives you*

Maybe my `dbConnection.close()` wont work because it's just a copy of Connection which Hikari gives me in `getConnection()` method.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. The whole point of a connection pool like HikariCP is to keep connections open for reuse. So that connections remain open is not unexpected, it is the whole point. When you call `close()` on a connection from a HikariCP datasource, it is returned to the connection pool, the connection is not physically closed.

Comment: I notice that all your connections have a different PID, that suggests that you are starting multiple processes that never end.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've used try-with-resource from Java 7 and now here's only 15 Idle connection, as I set in Max pool size. But they don't closes after idleTimeout. I've set maxLifetime and idleTimeout to default. Can it be because of auto-commit or something else? By the way, Connection's "Backend start" change sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to close also [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close())

```
try {
       if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
       }
       if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
       }
```

> Releases this Statement object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed. It is generally good practice to release resources as soon as you are finished with them to avoid tying up database resources.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're right. Can I use try-with-multiple resource? In my case with connection.getConnection() and PreparedStatement declaration to close them both?

Comment: @EDWIN it's possible, you can *try* by putting methods which return Connection PreparedStatement inside try-with-resources block

Comment: Is this ok to do this:
`try (Connection dbConnection = connector.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?")
        ) { `

What if `connector.getConnection()` return null, as I think it will be NullPointerException in this place `dbConnection.prepareStatement`

Comment: @EDWIN so let the method throw ConnectException instead of null. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703905/is-there-a-cleaner-way-to-use-try-with-resource-and-preparedstatement

Comment: You just saved my life. Thank you so much.

Comment: One last question, should I close ResultSet?

Comment: @EDWIN yes if you are using, but I didn't see in your question

Comment: A connection close should close a statement, and if you do close both explicitly, then you should close the statement **before** the connection.