# java. sql. SQLException: Before Start Of Result Set. how Can I Solve IT?

Tags: java, jdbc

How can I solve this error and what is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
     String sql = "select min(pressure),max(pressure),avg(pressure) from userinfo";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    String add1 = rs.getString("min(pressure)");
    min_pressure.setText(add1);
    String add2 = rs.getString("max(pressure)");
    max_pressure.setText(add2);
    String add3 = rs.getString("avg(pressure)");
    avg_pressure.setText(add3);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

This results in the exception:

> java. sql. SQLException: Before Start Of ResultSet

Comment: You should also use the [try-with-resources statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066501/how-should-i-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc) for managing JDBC resources efficiently and properly.

Comment: you might want to go through the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) javadoc says (in part) *initially the cursor is positioned before the first row.* Advance the resultset cursor to the first row by calling `next()` like

```
rs = pst.executeQuery();
rs.next(); // <-- or if (rs.next()) {
String add1 = rs.getString("min(pressure)");
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliot Frisch .Finally I solve it ....

Answer (score 0):

```
rs = pst.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    String add1 = rs.getStr
}
```