# Database Locked Exception in java with sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite

I am developing a java database application using sqlite in java. While I do INSERT and UPDATE operation, it throws sql exeption :

[SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked(database is locked)

Even I have closed the preparedStatement and the ResultSet in the finally clause as follows, It shows the same exeption.

```
   try {

        String sql = "Insert into cheque_log(description,pay,date,amount,profile,account_no,cross_cheque) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, txt_description.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txt_pay.getText());
        pst.setString(3, Date);
        pst.setString(4, txt_amount.getText());
        pst.setString(5, profile.getSelectedItem().toString().split("-")[0]);
        pst.setString(6, profile.getSelectedItem().toString().split("-")[1]);
        if (crosscheque_check.isSelected()) {
            pst.setString(7, "YES");
        } else {
            pst.setString(7, "NO");
        }

        pst.execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    } finally {

        try {
           pst.close();
           rs.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Where does it throw the exception? Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: Are doing something in [`SQLite DB Browser`](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) or some other application at the same time?

Comment: Also, you should learn about [`Try-With-Resources`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066501/how-should-i-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc).

Comment: No, It throws even when I run my application freshly without doing anything.

Comment: Still Having same problem @SedrickJefferson.

Comment: The problem is probably not this statement but some other one.

Comment: I agree with @CL. Download [`SQLite DB Browser`](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to see if you can operate on the DB with in it.

Comment: I would first restart my computer to make sure no other program has access to the DB.