# "java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed" after closing the connection

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, weblogic, sqlexception

I use weblogic application server and oracle database. I use jdbc for communicating with the oracle database. I get the connection from weblogic datasource and insert a record to the table. The problem is that when I want to close the connection (after inserting to the database) I'll face with an exception (Connection has already been closed) .This is my code:

```
private Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/datasource-uat");
        Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        return connection;
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


    public void persist(Long id) {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        if (id == 0L) {
            synchronized (this) {
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT MY_BEAN_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL");
                resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            }
            resultSet.next();
            id = resultSet.getLong("NEXTVAL");
        }

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MY_BEAN (ID) VALUES (?)");
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        connection.commit();
        if (resultSet != null) {
            resultSet.close();
        }
        preparedStatement.close();


    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        closeConnection(connection);
    }
}


private void closeConnection(Connection connection) {
    if (connection != null)
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

But connection.close statement throws an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.checkConnection(PoolConnection.java:62)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.preInvocationHandler(Connection.java:100)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.getMetaData(Connection.java:476)
at com.DataAccess.closeConnection(DataAccess.java:61)
at com.DataAccess.persist(DataAccess.java:289)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:181)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I tried to avoid connection.close statement (because I taught that connection is closed automatically!! but after a while all of the connections were opened and an exception was thrown due to that)

Comment: SO is full of questions covering this error message?  Did you do any research before posting?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Did you just remove your answer? Anyway, in my case I haven't any idea what is reason of this exception. Do you have?

Comment: add a check into closeConnection method if the connection is also still open, something like `if (connection != null && connection.isOpen())` (I don't remember the exact syntax)

Comment: @Leviand Scroll down in his code.  He is already doing this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no man, he's only checking if is != null

Comment: @Leviand where is connection closed? My whole code is that and I don't have any idea where connection is closed.

Comment: @Mohammad have you created a test that launches only 1 time this method? Possibilities could be many (calling concurrently this method, connection's xml setted for autoclose connections, etc etc)... let's start from a test

Comment: @Leviand Yes, I did. The exception was thrown

Comment: please add to your question the code of **datasource-uat**

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't seem to match the code. According to the stacktrace, `closeConnection` calls `getMetaData()`, while according to the code it class `close()`. Make sure you're posting the right code.

Comment: BTW: You could simplify your code a lot by using try-with-resources.

Comment: @Leviand datasource-uat has been set on weblogic. Id does not consist any special setting. You can see that in: http://tinypic.com/r/28qsu2p/9

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Be sure that it's the right code. I don't call getMetaData(), and I use jdk6

Comment: Then you are executing different code than you think you are, because that stacktrace doesn't lie that `com.DataAccess.closeConnection` (line 61) is calling `getMetaData` on the weblogic JDBC connection wrapper.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i don't call getMetaData, but weblogic does

Comment: Be aware that this will happen if you're setting "setRemoveAbandoned(true)" on your datasource. Any transaction that goes beyond the timeout you specify in that case will have been closed by the time it actually completes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to "automatically" close your connection.

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066501/how-should-i-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc)

Comment: I use jdk 6, so I cant use try-with-resources.