# There is no error but the data is not getting inserted into the database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a sql database into which i want to insert data. Below is my code .After executing the java program data dosen't get inserted into the database and neither an error occurs.

```
Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Username");
    String username=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Email");
    String email=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Phone Number");
    int phno=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Create a Password");
    String password=sc.next();
    
    
    try {
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample","root","abc");
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String query1="select * from login_details";
        String query2="insert into login_details(user_name,user_email,user_phone,user_password)values('"+username+"','"+email+"','"+phno+"','"+password+"')";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query1);
        boolean status=false;
        
        while(rs.next()) {
            if(status=false) {
                stmt.executeUpdate(query2);
                System.out.println("Details Entered Successfully");
            }
        }
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Typo: `if(status=false)` -> `if(status == false)`

Comment: What kiner_shah said above is the cause of your problem. However, you also need to read about the dangers of [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Tried that still the same...

Comment: this code is missing the handling of the open connection --> you should use the try-with-resource java feature (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066501/how-should-i-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc)

Then also no transaction is in use which can also lead to the mentioned issue.
If it is not using auto-commit you are never persisting anything to the database.

Comment: @n-n-nebbl auto-commit mode is the default of new connections created through `DriverManager` (technically, it is supposed to be the default of any connection, but some `DataSource` implementations allow you to configure a different default).

Comment: This code doesn't handle when your login_details table is empty. tbh, it doesn't make sense even with that fixed, so you might wanna go back to the drawing board and think about what you want to do. You should probably check if the entered values exist and if not exist then create new rows, but i have no idea

Answer (score 1):

There are logic and safety problems in the code.

You give value to the variable in the condition, instead of checking it. You should use:

```
if (!status){...}
```

The other thing that you should use PreparedStatement instead of Statement if datas come from the user. It is against of the sql injection attack.

Comment: Don't `select *` either. Select the unique criteria - probably username and password. Then you can do `if(!rs.next())`, making 'status' redundant

Answer (score 0):

When I look at this code, it will insert more doubled entries, the more entries are in the table.

I do not know, what you want to achieve while looping the content of the table and inserting the values one typed in.

When I assume, you want to check if a user already exists, it is worth to check if the user is there, before inserting it.

And I agree with all to use prepared statements. Try something like this:

```
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement reader=null;
PreparedStatement writer=null
ResultSet rs=null;

boolean userExists = false;
Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Username");
String username=sc.next();
System.out.println("Enter Email");
String email=sc.next();
System.out.println("Enter Phone Number");
int phno=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Create a Password");
String password=sc.next();


try {
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample","root","abc");
    reader=conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) NumberOfUsers from login_details where user_name = ?" );      
    reader.setString(1,username);
    rs = reder.executeQuery();
    if ( rs.next() ) {
       if ( rs.getInt(1) > 0 ) {
         userExists = true;
         System.out.println("Username already exists");
       }     
    }
    
    if ( ! userExists ) {
        writer = conn.prepareStatement("insert into login_details(user_name,user_email,user_phone,user_password)values(?,?,?,?)");
        writer.setString(1,username);
        writer.setString(2,email);
        writer.setInt(3,phno);  // is it really integer?
        writer.setString(4,password);
        
        writer.executeUpdate();
            
    }
    
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if ( reader ! = null ) {
       try {
          reader.close();
       } catch ( SQLException s ) {
          System.out.println("Error while closing reader " + s.getMessage());
       }
    }  
    if ( writer ! = null ) {
       try {
          writer.close();
       } catch ( SQLException s ) {
          System.out.println("Error while closing writer " + s.getMessage());
       }
    } 
    if ( rs ! = null ) {
       try {
          rs.close();
       } catch ( SQLException s ) {
          System.out.println("Error while closing ResultSet " + s.getMessage());
       }
    }       
    if ( conn ! = null ) {
       try {
          conn.close();
       } catch ( SQLException s ) {
          System.out.println("Error while closing Connection " + s.getMessage());
       }
    }
    

}
```